Firebase Google Authentication Window Popup Close Error Delay
Short and sweet:

When closing / dismissing the Google sign-in popup (key commands OR tapping X), why is the (auth/popup-closed-by-user) error received almost 7 seconds delayed?.

Any ideas here? I'd like it to throw the error immediately... for many reasons.
I've tested this on several occasions and it's consistently delayed. Running on Safari 17.2.1 on MacBook Pro 2021

import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-app.js'
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider, getAdditionalUserInfo } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-auth.js'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "********",
    authDomain: "********"
  }

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()

export function signInWithGoogle(callback) {
    auth.languageCode = 'it'
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
        .then((result) => {

            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result)
            const token = credential.accessToken
            const user = result.user
            const { isNewUser } = getAdditionalUserInfo(result) 
            callback(null, user, isNewUser)

        }).catch((error) => {

            const errorCode = error.code
            const errorMessage = error.message
            const email = error.customData.email
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error)
            console.log(errorMessage)
            callback(error, null, false)

        })

}

